# Record intermediary results in sympy

Tags: sympy

I am doing some operations on two [matrices](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/matrices.html#matrices) in sympy and I want to record how the result was obtained. For example in a `isympy` session:

```
a = Matrix([[1, 0], [2, 1]])
b = Matrix([[1, 1], [0, 2]])

out = HadamardProduct(a,b).doit()
out = sum(out)
out
```

Output:

```
3
```

Instead I would like this output:

```
1 * 1 + 0 * 1 + 2 * 0 + 1 * 2 = 3
```

How do I keep track of the history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be it:

```
a = Matrix([[1, 0], [2, 1]])
b = Matrix([[1, 1], [0, 2]])

with evaluate(False):
    out = a.multiply_elementwise(b)
    out = sum(out)

Eq(out, out.simplify())
```

Output:

```
2⋅0 + 0⋅1 + 0 + 1⋅1 + 1⋅2 = 3
```